# How to break softly a symmetry

Tags: quantum-field-theory, symmetry, symmetry-breaking, beyond-the-standard-model

If you start from a theory (non-SUSY) with whatever symmetry and you break it by adding a soft term. Do you have to add to your Lagrangian all possible soft terms that break the symmetry? If so, why?
If it's consistent not to add every term, what is the criteria? Could your model become non-renormalizable or inconsistent?

The question comes because in the model-building literature you see many times soft breaking of symmetries (mostly discrete symmetries) where the authors add certain soft terms but not all. This seems quite arbitrary and I would like to know if this is formally correct and why.

In short, if you soft-break a symmetry what are you forced to add to be consistent?